# Can't access Vuex getters outside of modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am unable to access the getters from one of my Vuex modules in my component, even though I can see the getter in Vue Dev Tools.

My `store.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import subsub from './modules/subsub';

Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: { },
  actions: { },
  mutations: { },
  getters: { },
  modules: {
    subsub,
  },
});
```

My `modules/subsub.js` file:

```
const state = {
  categories: [{
    name: 'one',
    path: 'two',
    ...
  }, {
    name: 'twocat',
    path: 'two',
    ...
  }],
};

const actions = { };
const mutations = { };
const getters = {
  filterCategories(state) {
    return state.categories;
  },
  filtertwo(state) {
    const filteri = state.categories.filter((catee) => {
      return catee.name === 'twocat';
    });
    return filteri;
  },
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters,
};
```

My component:

```
<template>
  <div> {{ filterCategories }} </div>
</template>

<script>    
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'categories',
      'filtertwo',
      'filterCategories',
    ]),
    filtertwo() {
      return this.$store.getters.filtertwo;
    },
    filterCategories() {
      return this.$store.getters.filterCategories;
    },
  },

</script>
```

So, what I am missing? Is there any other syntax for accessing the getters from modules?

Comment: You're not getting any errors in the console? Are you passing in the store when you instantiate Vue?

Comment: I am not getting any errors in the console. what do you mean to pass in the store when I instantiate Vue ?? .. by the way I tried using @click event for getter and that even didn't work

Comment: Wherever you instantiate the main app Vue component (probably `main.js`). You should be importing the vuex store and including that in the config object passed in `new Vue({...})`

Comment: /* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App, Icon },
});

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you don't have a getter for `categories`, so you need to add one.

Second, your `subsub` module has its `namespaced` property set to `true`. This means that you need to provide the module name to the `mapGetter` helper:

```
...mapGetters('subsub', [
  'categories',
  'filtertwo',
  'filterCategories',
]),
```

Third, the `mapGetters` function creates the `filtertwo`, and  `filterCategories` computed properties for you. But, you are redefining them manually, returning the explicit reference to the `$store.getters`. However, you aren't referencing the namespace correctly, so they are returning `undefined`. Either get rid of these computed properties or reference the namespace correctly:

```
filtertwo() {
  return this.$store.getters['subsub/filtertwo'];
},
filterCategories() {
  return this.$store.getters['subsub/filterCategories'];
},
```

Comment: In my vuex Dev Tool I see this: 
subsub/filterCategories:Array[2]
' subsub/filterCategories:Array[2]
0:Object
1:Object
subsub/filtertwo:Array[1]
0:Object '

Comment: I just added the subsub since my namespace property is set true (thnx for this I didn't know), but still I do not get any data into my component, and while using Vue Dev tool when entering Vuex Tab I see getters, but once I go to my router-view at components tab I get: filterCategories:undefined
filtertwo:undefined

Comment: @Marketingexpert, I didn't notice that you were redefining the `filterCategories` and `filterTwo` computed properties. That's why you were still getting `undefined`. You should use `mapGetters` or create computed properties manually, but not both. See my updated answer.

Comment: your updated question made a lot sense to me right now ;) I really appreciate your time and help. Learned a lot

Comment: @Marketingexpert glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thnx to hints from @thanksd

By using the example above where namespaced is set true I had to add the following to the component

```
filterCategories() {
      return this.$store.getters['subsub/filterCategories'];
    },
```

Otherwise, if I didn't want to add the subsub, I could just set the namespaced to false.
This issue took me a while to get my head around. 
Cheers